# Correct loading of jquery and usage of extended base.html templates within Django framework

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I think this is not very related to Django more to jQuery and html behavior however what is the problem statement:

Using a more or less standard base.html template

**base.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <!-- load Stylesheets -->
    {% endblock stylesheets %}

    <title>
        {% block title %}
        Base Title
        {% endblock title%}
    </title>

</head>

<body>
    <header>
        {% block header %}
        {% endblock %}
    </header>

    <main>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>

    <footer>
        {% block footer %}
        {% endblock %}
    </footer>

    {% block scripts %}
        <!-- Jquery 3.5.1 CDN -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Popper 1.12.9 CDN -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap 4.0.0 CDN -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block extrascripts %}
    {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

From this **dashboard.html** is derived by extension of **base.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Dashboard{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand justify-content-end">
        some navigation bar content
    </div>
    
        some else stuff

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 1em">
            {% include 'dash_cards/dash_card.html' %}
        </div>
    </div>

       some more content

{% endblock %}

{% block extrascripts %}

{% endblock %}
```

This works all fine and bootstrap is rendered fine - no jQuery elements are in at the moment
for the better readability and easier handling the dash card is in its own file and included into **dashboard.html** as you can see in above snippet.

The content of **dash_card.html** is as follows:

```html
<div class="card bg-darker col-md-6 border border-light">
    <!-- A grey horizontal navbar that becomes vertical on small screens -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <canvas id="BVChart" width="75%" data-url="{% url 'url:link' %}"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <-- some other fancy stuff -->
    </div>
</div>


{% block extrascripts %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
some js code to get the BVChart in the dash card canvas

    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

***Question 1:*** Why do I need to explicitly load jquery twice? Once in the base.html and once in the dash_card.html? If I don't do the jquery code of dash_cards.html is not executed.
My approach of all those separate blocks in base.html follows [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264493/jquery-from-base-html-not-working-in-other-templates-in-django) as well as some other using {{block.super}} but non of those works for me

Just to be sure - May somebody pls confirm this - this is not an loading (time) issue as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53511651/jquery-not-recognized-in-extended-html-python-flask/53515934)?!

***Question 2:*** As the current situation does not work properly (duplicate code) - jQuery must be loaded each time upwards of jquery code - What is the way forward? I just want to load it once and use it along the whole templates...

Thanks to all for your support and your input!

**EDIT**
As requested here is the some js Code to draw the chart...
I have too small hands to hold 2 hammers - the reason I asked LOL
This (document.ready function) is something I also thought of first but unfortunately this does not work

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('BVChart').getContext('2d');
var options = $.ajax({
url: $("#BVChart").attr("data-url"),
   async: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   }).responseJSON;

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: options.labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: options.data,
            borderColor: "#fff",
            borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
            label: '# of else',
            data: options.data2,
            borderColor: "#999",
            borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {beginAtZero: true}
                }]
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Your edit shows a weird ajax request:

```
var options = $.ajax({
  url: $("#BVChart").attr("data-url"),
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
}).responseJSON;
```

1. There is no data sent
2. There is not `success` callback...

In short, you are sending no data, just resquesting a result... Okay, possible. But there is nothing to handle that *plain* result.

So what is the purpose of that resquest then?

And what is `.responseJSON;` ? Don't you have any console error about that?

---

> Why do I need to explicitly load jquery twice?

You should not. Loading jQuery twice in a single page is like holding two hammers in one hand. lol... You just can break things and hurt yourself. :) hahaha

Now... The interesting JS code was not posted:

> some js code to get the BVChart in the dash card canvas

I guess you just need to wrap all this code with a document.ready() handler.

```
document.ready(function(){
  // The unposted code goes here.
}
```

So it runs when the `DOMContentLoaded` event has fired (the page completely loaded).

Comment: Hey - just double checked - No there is no error just a warning that it's depreciated.. anyhow - yes its just requesting the json data coming from the Django.view into the Chart function.
Here I followed [this blog post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2020/01/19/how-to-use-chart-js-with-django.html) Example 2
I'm a js noob and its pretty hard for me - what would be your proposal?

Comment: Have a closer look at the `home.html` part of the example. The `success` function is executed when the json is received from the ajax request. `data` is that json response.

Comment: Sorry I can't follow here - there is no home.html nor a success function used

Comment: I'm talking about the example from the tutorial you mentionned... In example #2, the `home.html` code.

Comment: Ah about that you speak - hmm oh I see Thanks yes and finally also the document.ready function makes sense! Thanks a lot